# php $ in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, svg, syntax

I integrated a star-rating feature (https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg) in a project.

I'm calling the script in a php loop like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    //the rating div
        echo '<div class="my-rating'.$row['id'].' jq-stars"></div>';

    //construct instance of star-rating
        echo "<script>
        $(function() {
        $(\".my-rating".$row['id']."\").starRating({
           starSize: 25,

//THE NEXT LINE CONTAINS THE PROBLEMATIC $-sign:     
           callback: function(currentRating, $el){
                alert('rated ', currentRating);
           }
         });
         </script>";
}
```

As PHP is interpretating the $ ($el) even if it's in an uninterupted echo-tag, the script is broken. What can I do to still use the callback function even if I need to call the script in the look?

Thanks for your effort, time and help!

Comment: Wrap it in `single-quote`

Comment: You don't even need that $el variable, your callback function doesn't use it. Just remove it, is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback function doesn't need the `$el` argument at all, you can just remove it, like this:

```
callback: function(currentRating) {
    alert('rated ', currentRating);
}
```